# SwiftUI Open view deep in NavigationView from push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, swiftui, ios-navigationview

I want to open a view after taping on a push notification. The views and notifications are all working fine but my problem is when I try to open the view from the push notification via .sheet(isPresented) it is always presenting the view as modal.

I would like to achieve that the view is actually opened embedded in the NavigationView it would usually be when accessing it manually.

To make it more clear:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: ListView()){
                    Text("Going one level down")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    
    var body: some View{
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()){
            Text("Click me")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View{
        Text("I want to display this view after tapping on a notification.")
    }
}
```

After tapping on the push notification, I want to jump directly to the DetailView() down in the NavigationView tree (similar to what the Apple Calendar app is doing when you tap on the notification).

Any ideas?

Comment: Same as https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/654490